# How to monitor and kill a process automatically on windows by process name

Tags: windows, process, kill

Is there a program or utility to monitor the running process and automatically kill specific processes?  My work laptop has a whole bunch of useless crap that I cannot uninstall.  Some of these processes keeps popping a specific intervals and consume tons of cpu and make my laptop useless.  I always have to manually kill these processes which is annoying.  I can't uninstall these otherwise they will automatically reinstall.

Answer (score 6):

you can make a vbscript, (or batch), then run as scheduled task,eg

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strProcess = objArgs(0)
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name ='" & strProcess & "'")

If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo strProcess & " is not running."
Else
    Wscript.Echo strProcess & " is running."
    'Kill the process
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next

End If
```

save the above as terminate.vbs and put this as schedule task

```
cscript /nologo terminate.vbs "sleep.exe"
```

Comment: I need to do greater than a threshold but `colProcesses.Count > 2` always return True. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching a debugger to the process and break.  It shouldn't pop up anymore (since it's still running), but it shouldn't bother you anymore either (from the break).  Apparently one of my co-workers used to do this to avoid automatic reboots after installing updates.

Answer (score 1):

**[AnVir Task Manager](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free.shtml)**

> Freeware process and startup manager.
>   Remove spyware and optimize
>   performance. Monitor and manage
>   processes, services, internet
>   connections, DLLs, drivers.
>   Descriptions for startup programs and
>   all Windows services. Alerts on new
>   startups.
>
> Icons in tray for CPU usage and disk
>   load. Quick access to last launched
>   programs in tray. Hide windows to
>   system tray.
>
> Automatically change process priority,
>   permanently block undesired processes.
>   Furthermore, comes with an attractive
>   user interface.
>
> Advanced startup manager allows you
>   to: · Get full list of applications
>   running automatically on Windows
>   startup including all hidden
>   applications. · Get all additional
>   information about startup
>   applications. · Disable/enable,
>   add/delete, edit startup entries. ·
>   Stop or run once again startup
>   application.
>
> Startup guard allows you to: · See
>   alert when any new application adds
>   itself to startup. · Forbid some
>   applications to be added to startup. ·
>   See alert when Internet Explorer home
>   page was changed.
>
> Process manager allows you to: · Get
>   full information about all processes:
>   CPU and memory usage, executable name
>   with full path, priority, work time,
>   user name. · Get executable file
>   properties, icon and version
>   information. · Stop many processes
>   with one click. · Change process
>   priorities.
>
> Tray icons allows you to: · Get
>   current information about CPU usage
>   including list of most active
>   programs. · Get current information
>   about HDD usage. Protection against
>   viruses includes: · Detection and
>   destruction of most propagated
>   viruses. · Virus database update. ·
>   Minimum usage of system resources.

*A free and portable version can be downloaded [here](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm).*

however, you may consider the **Pro** version, to permanently block undesired processes:

> create a 'black list' of **processes that are automatically terminated immediately after these processes start**. Add to this list annoying and undesired processes that are started automatically without your will.

*Anvir Task Manager Pro is shareware, try before you buy.*

Answer (score 1):

If app blacklisting is enough for you, so you could take a look at [Process Blocker](http://www.processblocker.com) it's free. Process can be blocked by its name (with wildcard support in paths and names), as well by its CRC32.

In paid version it has some [additional features](http://www.processblocker.com/purchase.html), such as whitelisting by process name, CRC32, and logged on username or user's group.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.

Comment: David, I have added details

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not free :( 10 day trial

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Microsoft TechNet.

Comment: Can it automatically kill a process?

Comment: AFAIK no, but with PE he can detect which program starts that process and then remove that program forever. Why killing a process every time the computer starts instead of finding its root and removing it permanently? If he wants to kill a process, it means that he won't need it.

Comment: I know which program it is, i cannot uninstall it or IT will magically reinstall it somehow in the background... trust me i've tried

Comment: Then Molly's answer is the right one. But I wonder: If you install a 3rd party software like AnVir, won't IT warn you? IMHO, you should tell them about those decelerators and they should find the solution.

Comment: ideally yes, but they don't care.  It is a pos backup software, backs up *everything*, non-configurable, and doesn't care if you're at home on the wireless, or whatever, and also takes up tons of cpu... cannot be disable, or scheduled, they are adamant we keep it installed, but don't know if we kill it every chance we get (which we do)

Comment: there's also an equally horrendous anti-spyware program... don't get me started...

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity, and I wish you patience with that IT :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know Microsoft Developer Tools, you can use PSAPI (Process status API) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684884(VS.85).aspx to write nifty utility to do the things you want.

Answer (score 0):

Start msconfig from "Run program..." in the start menu.
It allows you to disable programs started from the registry.
The same goes for services too.

But I wonder. Is it your own laptop, or a company laptop. If the latter, then it might be something configured in the group policy that installs the programs again.