# “utorrent.exe” simply will not end

Tags: windows-7, process

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Kill window or application just like linux do](https://superuser.com/questions/66176/kill-window-or-application-just-like-linux-do)
>   [Cannot Kill Process in Vista 64](https://superuser.com/questions/66474/cannot-kill-process-in-vista-64)

I had closed an instance of `utorrent`. The task no longer appears in Applications, however the process `utorrent.exe` appears in Processes tab of Task Manager. I tried to kill using:

- Kill process button in Task Manager
- Kill process option in SysInternals Process Explorer
- Suspend, resume, restart in SysInternals Process Explorer
- command prompt by using the command `taskkill /f /im utorrent.exe`
- `Stop-Process` commandlet in Windows PowerShell.

All of these have failed, the process just doesn't end. I cannot restart uTorrent because of the existing process running. Is there anyway I can kill this without having to resort to a system reboot ? I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, OEM.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/66176/kill-window-or-application-just-like-linux-do http://superuser.com/questions/48864/shortcut-to-kill-an-application http://superuser.com/questions/69783/how-to-monitor-and-kill-a-process-automatically-on-windows-by-process-name

Comment: Sathya, have you tried *pskill.exe* from SysInternals?

Comment: Could something be respawning this process?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/66474/cannot-kill-process-in-vista-64/124937#124937

Comment: You don’t need to kill it. The problem is that it still has open network connections and is waiting for them to close. You can try closing them manually (e.g., with [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)), but sometimes µTorrent gets stuck in a loop where it opens new connections while waiting for others to close (usually when you have a lot of active torrents running). To “kill” it, simply block µTorrent from the Internet (probably easier to just disconnect the whole system). Then `utorrent.exe` will end ~2 seconds later.

Comment: In addition, I have learned a long time ago that there are certain things that will cause a program to become “unkillable”. It usually ends up being due to some sort of unusual resource being in use (thus likely due to a driver problem). Some of these include programs that use tv-tuners, optical drives, and network connections. Occasionally they will “super-lock” for some reason and pretty much the only way to kill them is to reboot.

Comment: Regarding open connections - That isn't necessarily true.  I can clearly view that there are no connections being used on the entire machine other than 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, and various connections between other machines on my lan that are not being made with utorrent. It still won't close. I usally use TakeCommand's taskend to kill it.