# Cannot end Windows 7 process, even tried pskill

Tags: windows, process, kill, tasks

I am having a problem where processes are hanging and absolutely refuse to die. I have tried using the task manager and `pskill` from the console (with admin rights) and while the program will state that it has killed the process it still remains and I cannot open a second process. This has happened with Opera and Truecrypt.

Operating system is Windows 7 Professional (64-bit). Rebooting the computer clears the hung process.

I also tried using a program called [Ultimate Process Detail & Killer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ultmprokill/), which didn't help either.

Comment: @Chris Have a look at the related links [over here](http://superuser.com/questions/125293/killing-an-unresponsive-process)

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?, have you run a System File Checker?, have you run a chkdsk /f?

Comment: @Moab Tried all that too. Highly annoying to have to reboot everytime this happens. I finally let Truecrypt sit, after about 20 minutes it finally closed on its own.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Truecrypt? I have had this happen with other applications, I do what you did after terminating the process, just wait, sometimes that is the best solution.

Comment: @Moab: Yes, I have the latest version of Truecypt. I don't want to point at Truecrypt as the culprit as I've experienced it with Opera too. It's like the memory for said application goes into limbo for 20+ minutes before coming out. Opera never came out.

Comment: That is unusual for W7, Might be some sort of driver conflict. You might try using Reliability Monitor to see if anything got logged...http://www.msigeek.com/5518/measure-hardware-and-software-problems-using-reliability-monitor-in-windows-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Try the debugger:

  ```
   ntsd -p <pid> -c q
  ```
- Processes can be unkillable if they are waiting for an I/O or similar operation to finish ("uninterruptible sleep") (see also [[1]](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373#191459))
- or if they are [*already dead*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040723-00/?p=38363)<sup>1</sup> (aka "zombie processes" in Unix).

  *<sup>1</sup>The Old New Thing:* [Why do some process stay in Task Manager after they've been killed?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040723-00/?p=38363)

Comment: what exactly is the ntsd command? any links to the uses, thanks.

Comment: @Moab: `ntsd` is _Windows NT Symbolic Debugger_, part of Windows XP and later. (The `q` command means just "quit".) There's some information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks grawity, So that command tells the process to quit? what does -p and -c mean, thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Moab: They're *options*: `-p` tells the program that the following argument is a numeric process ID to attach to; similarly, `-c` precedes a single command - without it, you would get ntsd's interactive mode.

Comment: Is there any chance to see what does it wait for? Because Miranda and Skype both hang like this and I can't see what may be the core problem, that I need to solve :(

Comment: @TomášFejfar: in Process Explorer or Process Hacker, open process properties → threads → thread stack; it *might* give some clues

Comment: Ah, nice. I'll try it next time it happens

Comment: The feed back I got, trying to kill a Visual Studio debuggee is: Cannot debug pid 4580, NTSTATUS 0xC0000048                                                                                     "An attempt to set a process's DebugPort or ExceptionPort was made, but a port already exists in the process or an attempt to set a file's CompletionPort made, but a port was already set in the file or an attempt to set an ALPC port's associated completion port was made, but it is already set."
Debuggee initialization failed, NTSTATUS 0xC0000048 (continues on next comment)

Comment: (continuation) An attempt to set a process's DebugPort or ExceptionPort was made, but a port already exists in the process or an attempt to set a file's CompletionPort made, but a port was already set in the file or an attempt to set an ALPC port's associated completion port was made, but it is already set.

Comment: Cannot debug pid 41236, NTSTATUS 0xC000010A
    "已尝试访问正在退出的过程。"
Debuggee initialization failed, NTSTATUS 0xC000010A
已尝试访问正在退出的过程。
ntsd: exiting - press enter ---

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command:

```
Taskkill /IM **.exe /F
```

Comment: `ERROR: The process "GitHub.exe" with PID 11112 could not be terminated. Reason: There is no running instance of the task.`

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score -1):

**Space Tornado Killer** might do the trick, as I have it installed on my PC.

Space Tornado Killer is a free Windows utility that allows you to end/kill multiple running Windows processes at once, with one click of a button. Hold down Ctrl and click to select one, two, three or any number of processes. Then simply click Kill Selected or hit F4 to end all the selected processes at once.

This utility is designed to complement Task Manager, not replace it.

For further details & to download

http://www.spacetornado.com/killer/