# Have local admin privileges on Windows XP, but getting "Error terminating process: Access is denied". How to kill the process?

Tags: windows-xp, process, kill, process-explorer

On one of the Windows XP machines I use regularly, there is a process that starts up periodically.  I'd like to be able to kill the process – sometimes – because it occasionally runs when I'm busy doing something machine-intensive.

I've already tried dropping the process priority to "Idle" to mitigate the effects, but it isn't the CPU that's the problem.  Rather, the process is very disk-intensive and no matter the process priority, it still causes significant disk thrashing when running, impacting everything else I'm doing at the time.

Using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), I can find the process, right-click, and choose **Kill Process**, but I always get the message **"Error terminating process: Access is denied."**

This is not an operating system process, but third-party software.  What might that process be doing to prevent itself from being terminated?

How can I kill such a process?  Is there a way for me to modify the process's security or access control list (ACL) somewhere, using Process Explorer or another tool, so that I can effectively kill it?

Comment: potential dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/48864/shortcut-to-kill-an-application or http://superuser.com/questions/66176/kill-window-or-application-just-like-linux-do ... also http://superuser.com/questions/69783/how-to-monitor-and-kill-a-process-automatically-on-windows-by-process-name or http://superuser.com/questions/66474/cannot-kill-process-in-vista-64 ... or try browsing thru [this list](http://superuser.com/search?q=%22kill%22+%22process%22+%22windows%22)

Comment: @quack quixote: Thanks, but none of those questions deal with the "Access denied" issue central to this question. I'm also asking if there's a way to modify the process security/ACL, and I don't see those questions asking that either.

Comment: Though I do see http://superuser.com/questions/109010 .. *very* close, but no cigar; I'm asking re: XP x86, not Win7 x64.

Comment: Can you tell us the process name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I'm able to kill the process in question using **[Process Hacker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/processhacker/)**, which, coincidentally, I learned about today from a [SuperUser Community Promotion Ad](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2164/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011#2824):

[image: Process Hacker: more than you ever wanted from Process Explorer.]

One of the features listed is "powerful process termination".  From the project page:

> Process Hacker is a free and open source process viewer and memory
>   editor with unique features such as **powerful process termination.** It
>   can show services, processes and their threads, modules, handles and
>   memory regions.  *[emphasis mine]*

While I don't intend for to replace Process Explorer, this is certainly a complementary new tool worth keeping around, and I'm curious to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
at 16:44 /Interactive taskmgr.exe
```

This would add a job to the scheduler to run the taskmgr.exe at 16:44. Select your time about 1 minute in the future from current time. The taskmgr.exe would run with the System account which has additional privileges. See if it works.

Comment: Running interactive tasks is dangerous.

Comment: @kinokijuf , dangerous but not in this case. Registry is dangerous too... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The process could be starting with the SeShutdownPrivilege set to Deny (or not set to Allow) for you or the group you're in.

Fire up `procexp.exe`, find the process, right-click --> Properties --> Security tab --> Permissions button.  You may need to run `procexp.exe` elevated to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

taskkill /f will do it!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but here was the result: *ERROR: The process with PID nnnn could not be terminated. Reason: Access is denied.*

Comment: and you had the /f typically I have cygwin installed and a kill -9 works everytime so I was hoping that taskkill /f would to this!  if you do sc /queryex processname you should see the reason for not being able to kill the process.

Comment: I also have cygwin installed.  "kill -9 nnnn" reports: *bash: kill: (nnnn) - No such process* ... I don't even think cygwin's kill sees this process since it isn't a cygwin process.  "ps -ef" only lists bash and ps.

Comment: how about
wmic process where "processid='xxxx'" delete

Answer (score 0):

What is the software?  Sounds like it's running as a service.  You'll get that error when you try to kill a process (from Task Manager or Process Explorer) that is running as a services.